# Get XML string from DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

How can I get the XML generated by DOM parser to be stored in string variable in Java? I can store it in `.xml` file using:

```
// creating and writing to xml file  
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();  
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);  
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("d:/xml_created.xml"));
transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
```

but I need to get it stored in a string variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `StringWriter` and print the XML to that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

transformer.transform(domSource, sw);

String xml = sw.toString();
```

You may need to wrap the `StringWriter` in an `OutputStream`, I can't remember off hand.